# Writing image sprites using response

Tags: java, javascript, css, servlets

I'm just new to image sprites and hence don't know how to solve my problem. Well, my problem is I have to generate an image sprite dynamically at the server and receive it using an AJAX call made from the browser. I would like to use the servlet's response object to write the image to the output stream and while receiving it at the browser, I want to slice the image sprite to individual pieces. Can this be accomplished? If yes, how can it be?

Comment: Jumping right to the deep end aren't we? What have you tried?

Comment: I don't know how my problem can be solved. I know its possible to transfer and display a single image using response object. But, I don't know how to transfer an img sprite and slice it at the browser(using css/javascript)

Comment: Can you name any reason for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you really want to try to retrieve the image with ajax. You could just tell the server how to generate the sprite with ajax, and then set an image source with javascript.

```
    submit_imageStuff = function ( ) {
    var imageStuff = $('#input').val ( ) ;
        type : 'POST' ,
        url : 'createImage.php' ,
        data : { imageStuff:imageStuff } ,
        success : function ( data ) { $('#newImageDiv').html ( data ) ; refresh_email ( ) ; }
```

As for how to slice the image sprite, check out css-tricks.com http://css-tricks.com/css-sprites/